# Is there a way to rewrite this SQL query with '(NOT) IN' instead of 'NOT EXISTS'?

Tags: sql, exists, not-exists, notin

The task was to write an SQL query that returns the first ever inaugurated president.
The two attributes used from the table `administration` should be self-explanatory.
Here you can see my solution which I'm confident in being correct.

```
SELECT A1.pres_name, A1.year_inaugurated
FROM administration A1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT NULL
     FROM administration A2
     WHERE A1.year_inaugurated > A2.year_inaugurated);
```

As I'm trying to learn SQL, I thought of any other ways to write this query but couldn't find any.
Are there any other solution that do not use `NOT EXISTS`?
But instead use `IN`, `NOT IN`, `EXISTS`?
Another constraint is to not use the `MIN` function.
And if there are than one solution that do not use `NOT EXISTS`, I would be very happy to see all of them to learn the most from it.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I'm not sure. I am very new to SQL and these president tables were already there when I installed SQL developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really write this using `NOT IN`, but you could write it using a scalar subquery:

```
SELECT A1.pres_name, A1.year_inaugurated
FROM administration A1
WHERE A1.year_inaugurated = (SELECT MIN(A2.year_inaugurated)
                             FROM administration A2
                            );
```

Or -- assuming that there are not any duplicate years -- using `ORDER BY` and a way to limit the rows:

```
SELECT A1.pres_name, A1.year_inaugurated
FROM administration A1
ORDER BY A1.year_inaugurated ASC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I like the alternative solutions you wrote there, they make alot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get the result that you want is with the operator [`ALL`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql):

```
SELECT pres_name, year_inaugurated
FROM administration
WHERE year_inaugurated <= ALL (SELECT year_inaugurated FROM administration)
```

Comment: I totally did not think of the ALL operator.. that's another good solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty much Gordon's 2nd answer, but I'm not familiar with `FETCH` in SQL server so I would use `top`.

```
select top(1) a1.pres_name, a1.year_inaugurated
from administration a1
order by a1.year_inaugurated asc
```

Comment: Yes this seems to be the same as Gordon's answer, however I didn't know the top syntax yet and it's good to know about it, thank you!